# How to NFS-export /Volumes/drive as /nfs/drive on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, mount, nfs

I've got the following `/etc/exports` entry on my Mac OS X machine:

```
/Volumes/a/long/path/to/folder -ro -alldirs -network 192.168.1.0 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

It works great, except I don't want it exported as `/Volumes/a/long/path/to/folder`, I want it as `/nfs/folder`.

Tried, symlinks, but doesn't work. Per manage:

> The pathnames must not have any symbolic links in them and should not
>   have any "." or ".." components.

What other options do I have to mount the folder as I'd like without having to install additional software?

Comment: (I use Linux, not OSX, so I can't advise specifics, hence a comment) - /etc/exports says [on the server] what can be exported.  In order to work out where its exported TO, you need to change the mount path on the **client**.  I imagine that OSX has a file /etc/fstab - and if so, you can (using a text editor) select the destination by adding a line like "server.ip:/Volumes/a/long/path/to/folder /nfs/folder nfs defaults 0 0" and then rebooting or typing mount -a to mount it.  You will need to make sure the directory /nfs/folder exists.

Comment: @davidgo My goal is to hide the specifics of the filesystem layout on the server, not simply have an easy-to-use path.

Comment: In that case you have an uphill battle.  I guess you could trick the file system layout by using an overlay filesystem of some sort  overlay filesystem like unionfs (see http://osx.iusethis.com/app/macfuse)  to make a mirror of the filesystem tree without using symlinks).  The heretic in me asks if you would not be better off using SAMBA and sharing the files using the Windows filesharing/CIFS protocol ?  (You have more control of mount points on the server in SAMBA)

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments, the only obvious two answers are:

1. Use a hard link in the place you want it to appear to come from - that should work! Or;
2. Move the material you want to export to the location you want it to appear to come from, so it "really is there", and then use a soft link from where you otherwise want it to be in your file system hierarchy.